# Is it possible to define two methods in a Rails model that require different initialization?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Hi I'm attempting to create a model in Rails that can perform two calculations. This is my code:

```
class Calculator
  def initialize(nair, cppy, interest_rate, payment, periods)
    @nair = nair.to_f / 100
    @cppy = cppy.to_f

    @interest_rate = interest_rate
    @payment = payment
    @periods = periods      
  end

  def effective
    Refinance::Annuities.effective_interest_rate(@nair, @cppy)          
  end

  def principal
    Refinance::Annuities.principal(@interest_rate, @payment, @periods)
  end
end
```

I have two forms that reside in different views that take input from the user including 'nair' and 'cppy' on one and 'interest_rate', 'payment' and 'periods' on the other.

The problem I've run into is that to use this model all five arguments need to be available.

Do I need to have separate models for each calculation?

I'm a complete beginning sorry if there is a really obvious answer.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's probably a dozen different ways you could solve this, but one possible approach would be to use default arguments in your initialize method.

```
class Calculator
  def initialize(nair=0, cppy=0, interest_rate=0, payment=0, periods=0)
    @nair = nair.to_f / 100
    @cppy = cppy.to_f

    @interest_rate = interest_rate
    @payment = payment
    @periods = periods      
  end

  def effective
    Refinance::Annuities.effective_interest_rate(@nair, @cppy)          
  end

  def principal
    Refinance::Annuities.principal(@interest_rate, @payment, @periods)
  end
end
```

Another possible solution is to make them class methods and not deal with instances or state:

```
class Calculator
  def self.effective(nair, cppy)
    nair = nair.to_f / 100
    cppy = cppy.to_f

    Refinance::Annuities.effective_interest_rate(nair, cppy)
  end

  def self.principal(interest_rate, payment, periods)
    Refinance::Annuities.principal(interest_rate, payment, periods)
  end
end

Calculator.effective(x, y)
Calculator.principal(x, y, z)
```